# CSS height animation on hover image/icon

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem with my icon when on hover. I want to replace my `img src` during on hover: heres my code so far:

```css
#aks {
  width: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/like.png") no-repeat;
  padding: 50px;
}

#aks:hover {
  background: url("https://img.icons8.com/officexs/32/000000/like.png")
    no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<img id="aks" src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/like.png" />
```

What I really want to achieve is when hovered on outline heart icon will replace with heart filled icon but during replacing the outline icon it will show/animate from bottom height 0 to full height so it look like it filled the outline icon. here some example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/caleuanhopkins/pen/penCB)

any alternatives or solutions other than this is highly appreciated.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible with two icons and the effect you mentioned.

Your best bet is to have another icon which is filled with outline and use a `fade-in` type of animation.

Comment: if possible can you post some samples about this one?

Comment: It is very similar to the answer posted below.
Just think in reverse order. 
We start with empty and end with filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly easy on a CSS-only heart because the sliding animation would have to be applied to three completely distinct elements (the rotated square, plus the two circles).

For the sake of thoroughness, here is an example using a font that includes a heart. For simplicity, I used Webdings but *you should use Font Awesome in actual live code*.

The summary is your background is a 2x taller gradient that is 50% white and 50% red, and you slide the background from showing the white half to instead showing the red half upon hover. Two important properties of this will *currently only work on webkit browsers*: `text-stroke`, which adds the outline to the text -- and `background-clip`, which clips the non-text portion of the `span`'s background.

```css
span {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, red 50%);
  color: transparent;
  font-family: webdings;
  font-size: 200px;
  transition: background-position 2s;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
  text-stroke-width: 5px;
  text-stroke-color: red;
}
span:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>Y</span>
```

Comment: No, SVG can't really be styled with CSS. You would have to do the actual animation within the SVG itself, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well if using `css` is an option for you then, you can take a look at this:

```css
.heart {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.heart::before,
.heart::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.heart::before {
  top: -15px;
}

.heart::after {
  left: 15px;
}

.heart:hover,
.heart:hover::before,
.heart:hover::after {
  background-color: #F5A9AE;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.heart {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response! How about an image like what I posted above? is it possible? it seems you create the heart from pure css here right?

Comment: Think about actual situation, `hover` is just filling the alternative at once right and you're trying to do it on image which fillin the image at once, however if you use `css` you have many option to play around as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with background animation like below:

```css
.heart {
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  padding-top:50px;
  background: 
    url("https://img.icons8.com/officexs/32/000000/like.png") bottom padding-box content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom padding-box content-box,
    url("https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/like.png");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.heart:hover {
   padding-top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```